# Parsing strings in a column with Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework

Our data model in one of the rows looks like:

```
productName.productDescriptor.productMetadata
```

There is not a lot of data in this table. Is there a "good" way to parse that data, like get all the

```
Products where productDescriptor equals <MyDescriptor>
```

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a query like this:

`var result = myRows.Where(x => x.myColumn.Contains("." + productDescriptor + "."));`

If the components of your strings contain the separator period, this will not work.